# variable initialization in class structure

Tags: python, class, variables

I am trying to initialize a function/method right in the init. 
so the self.y in class A returns the correct value of 10. Or maybe use a method get_y in A?

please refer to the codes below and the comments. Thanks

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
        self.y = None
        # self.y = B.eval(self)?? # wants y to be a value obtained from B.eval()
    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

    def get_y(self):
        # wants y to be a value obtained from B.eval()
        #return B.eval(self) ??

class B(object):
    def eval(ClassA):
        """
        :param ClassA: is an instance of A
        :return: value
        """
        return ClassA.get_x() + 5


a = A()
b = B()
print(a.get_y()) # wants value 10 printed out here
print(B.eval(a))
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is it you want to know?

Comment: You may wish to investigate the use of `property` —a property is an attribute that automatically runs user-defined code when you set, get or delete it:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example of what you're trying to achieve? What's the point of having `B` at all?

Comment: Thanks all. I wasn't sure of instance self. JetBrain was saying self.y = B.eval(self) was expecting the self from B but self is actually from A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `B.eval()` a `classmethod` by using it as a method decorator in `class B` as shown:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
        self.y = None
        self.y = B.eval(self)
    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

    def get_y(self):
        return B.eval(self)

class B(object):
    @staticmethod    # ADD THIS LINE
    def eval(ClassA):
        """
        :param ClassA: is an instance of A
        :return: value
        """
        return ClassA.get_x() + 5

a = A()
b = B()
print(a.get_y())  # -> 10
print(B.eval(a))  # -> 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. This was needed because `eval()` doesn't have a `self` argument and you were calling it without creating an instance: `B.eval(a)`. Note there's little to be gained by putting the definition of it in `class B` rather than just making it a free-standing function (with a name different from `eval` to avoid disabling the built-in function with the same name).